# bootstrap.css - How to hide sidebar when mobile?

Tags: css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to realize a layout with bootstrap.css. It is especially a main view with a right sidebar. It looks great on the desktop, but i am trying to remove the sidebar when i have a mobile view. 
Currently my layout looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span9">
         Main view goes here
      </div>
      <div class="span3 visible-desktop visible-tablet hidden-phone">
         Sidebar goes here
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So when i have a mobile view, the sidebar disappears. But the main view still has a span9 class, causing the whole view having some whitespace to the right. I am currently experiencing this on an iPhone 4 with mobile safari.

I am no css guru and i mainly work on the backend of webapps, but this time i just want to do it right, because it is for my personal blog. You can check out what i mean with this "whitespace" at [my blog](https://blog.simonszu.de). I know that the navbar isn't pretty at all now, but this will be the next thing i'll fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it on [www.responsinator.com](http://www.responsinator.com/?url=https://blog.simonszu.de/)
I guess there is no such white-spacing to the right. Moreover `row-fluid` class of bootstrap converts every child `span` class to full width when the site is opened on any other device except for desktop. So in any case, the `width:100%` is assigned to `span9` when you open it on iPhone4.

There seems to be a little space on the right cuz of two reasons probably:
1. Text is not justified.
2. `container-fluid` adds a padding of 20px to the left as well as right.

Hope it helps. :)